# Number Theory: Finding specific new square-triangular numbers given that (m, n) satisfied n^2=m(m+1)/2

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Ok, so I've been making my way through my beginning number theory homework, and I've come to this problem.  In all honesty, I don't even know where to start, so I would greatly appreciate any advice you have as to how to go about it.

Fill in the blanks with positive numbers so that the following statement is true:  If (m, n) gives a square triangular number, that is, if a pair (m, n) satisfies $n^2$ = $m(m$+1)/2, then (1+_m+_n, 1+_m+_n) also gives a square-triangular number.

Comment: The formula there.  http://www.artofproblemsolving.com/blog/100135

Answer (score 1):

what you are expected to do is pretty similar to induction. You start with a pair that satisfies $ m^2 + m = 2n^2.$  Your task is to find four positive integers $A,B,C,D$ that make $(1 + Am +Bn, 1 + C m + D n)$ is also a solution, in the order I wrote it would be
$$ (1 + Am+Bn)^2 + (1 + Am + Bn) = 2 (1 +Cm+Dn)^2.  $$
You just need to multiply it out, apply $m^2 + m = 2 n^2$ wherever applicable, and finally find $A,B,C,D.$

This problem, done from the start, goes through Pell type equations and the automorphisms of quadratic forms. They want you to just jump to the end.

Comment: Thank you!  I've multiplied it out, but when you say to apply the equation wherever applicable, does that mean I need to pull out various m's and change them to 2n^2's?

Comment: @Charlotte, well, replace each $n^2$ by $m(m+1)/ 2$ and see how far that gets you.